# jquery count xml nodes

Tags: jquery, xml

I am using jQuery ajax function to handle data tracking from database. The returned data in this function is like

```
<root>
  <result city='LA' state='CA'></result>
  <result city='DALLAS' state='TX'></result>
  ...
 </root>
```

I'm using

```
 var count=$(data).find("result").length();
```

to get count of result nodes, but it is not right.
So how to count result nodes using jQuery?

Comment: What value are you getting vs. what your expecting?

Comment: I will do different program based on the number of result node. If only one result node{}, if more than one{}, something like that.

Comment: Yes but what value is it returning that you think is invalid.  Is it saying 0 result values for example when there are say 10?

Comment: Error happens, says : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Function expected.

Comment: That means the actual ajax call is likely the problem.  Could you post the code for the ajax call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `data` is an XML Node object, `$(data).find("result").length` is fine. No brackets, `length` is a property not a method. There is a method that does the same thing, `size()`, though there's no real advantage to using it.

(If `data` were actually a string, you'd have to parse that into an XML document first. Passing non-HTML markup to `$()` is the wrong thing and only works sometimes by luck.)

Comment: It should be length without brackets.

Answer (score 1):

It's true length is not work here, I had same problem and I had solved it using `size()`
just like

```
var count=$(data).find("result").size();
```